# Proving two statements about locally compact spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

The problem statement:

Let $(X,d)$ be a locally compact metric space (for every $x \in X$, there exists a compact neighbourhood of $x$)

$a)$ Prove that if $K_1 \subset X$ is compact, then, there are $K_2 \subset X$ compact and $\eta>0$ : $K_1 \subset K_{2}^{\circ}$ and $d(x,y) \geq \eta$ if $x \in K_1$ and $y \not \in K_2$.

$b)$ Let $f: X \to \mathbb R$ a continuous function. Suppose that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a compact subspace $K_{\epsilon} \subset X$: $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ if $x \not \in K_{\epsilon}$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I am pretty lost with this exercise.

I've edited the two items and added the corresponding solutions:

For $a)$

If $K_1$ is a compact subspace and $x \in K_1$, by hypothesis, there exists $U_x$ a compact neighbourhood of $x$. Then, $K_1 \subset \bigcup_{x \in K_1} U_x$. Since $x \in U_x^{\circ}$ for every $x$, $\bigcup_{x \in K_1} U_{x}^{\circ}$ is an open cover of $K_1$, and, by hypothesis, there exist $1,2,...,n$ : $K_1 \subset \bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}^{\circ} \subset \bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}$. Since $\bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}$ is a finite union of compact spaces, then it is compact. If I call $K_2=\bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}$, then $K_1 \subset K_{2}^{\circ}$ and $K_2$ is compact.

It remains to prove there is $\eta>0$: if $x \in K_1$ and $y \not \in K_2$, then $d(x,y)\geq \eta$. Consider $f:K_1 \to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=d(x,K_{2}^c)$. As $f$ is a continuous function defined on a compact set, $f$ must attain a minimum: there is $x \in K_1: d(x,K_{2}^c)\leq d(z,K_{2}^c) \space \forall \space z \in K_1$. I don't know how to show that $\eta=d(x,K_{2}^c)>0$.

I've corrected part $b)$ after Berci's suggestions:

I've separated in the following cases:

If $x,y \not \in K_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$, by hypothesis we have that $|f(x)-f(y)|<|f(x)|+|f(y)|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

If $x,y \in K_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$, as $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$, there is $\delta_1: d(x,y)<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$

If $x \in K_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$ and $y \not \in K_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$, again, I consider two cases: 1) $y \in K_2$, then, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K_2$, so there is $\delta_2$: $d(x,y)<\delta_2 \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. If $y \not \in K_2$, we take $\delta_3<\eta$ (the case $y \in K_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}, x \not \in K_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$ is analogue).

Now, by taking $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3\}$, we have that $d(x,y)<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. This proves $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Good start. The sets $U_x$ are not only compact, they are also *neighborhoods* of $x$. This means that $x\in {U_x}^\circ$ and these interiors are *open*, so we have an open cover of $K_1$. Can you take it from here?

b) This separation of cases will work. Use the previous proposition: we have a compact $K_2$ and an $\eta>0$ such that ${K_2}^\circ\supseteq K_{\varepsilon/2}$ and $d(x,y)\ge \eta$ for $x\in K_{\varepsilon/2},\ y\notin K_2$. Now, consider the  following cases:

- $x,y\in K_2$
- $x\in K_{\varepsilon/2},\ y\notin K_2$
- $y\in K_{\varepsilon/2},\ x\notin K_2$
- $x,y\notin K_{\varepsilon/2}$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I could solve $b)$, now I'll write it, but I still have problems with $a)$. You've said to consider $\bigcup_{x \in K_1} U_x^{\circ}$ which is an open cover of $K_1$. Since $K_1$ is compact, there exist $1,2,...,n$: $K_1 \subset \bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}^{\circ}$. But from here I don't see so clear which is the compact $K_2$ I am looking for.

Comment: I've edited my post and added the solution to part $b)$ using your ideas. I got what I have to do in $a)$, as I've said in my previous comment, $K_1 \subset \bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}^{\circ}$, so $K_1 \subset \bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}$. Since a finite union of compact sets is compact, $K_2=\bigcup_{x_i \in K_1, 1\leq i \leq n} U_{x_i}$ was the set I was looking for.

Comment: Btw, your answer was really useful, thanks again.